# Horizontal Pods Autoscaling (HPA) on GKE based on GPU utilization

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, hpa

I am trying to achieve Horizontal Pods Autoscaling (HPA) in GCP based on GPU utilization.
My hpa.yaml file looks like this:

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-hpa
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
     metricName: kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle
      targetAverageValue: 10
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-container-worker
```

After I run `kubectl create -f hpa.yaml` , I see the following error in the GCP.

[image]

On the HPA, it says unable to read all metrics.

In stack driver monitoring I have created a dashboard with the metric mentioned above.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: try using `compute.googleapis.com|container|accelerator|duty_cycle`

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working either.. I get the same error

Comment: Make sure you deployed [Custom Metrics Stackdriver Adapter](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling#step1) correctly and that its *Running*. I just created a gke cluster with hpa and gpus and all seems to be working for me.

Comment: Thank you.. It seem to be working now. I just need to figure out the targetAverageValue that works. What do you usually set it to?

Comment: Now I get, this error when I run kubectl describe hpa 

`Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  43m                 horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle external metric: unable to get external metric default/kubernete
s.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{},MatchExpressions:[],}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (
get kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle.external.metrics.k8s.io)`

Comment: Did I forget anything here.

Comment: Notice `43m`, meaning this event is 43 minutes old so it is probably event from before you deployed Custom Metrics Stackdriver Adapter.

Comment: To figure out `targetAverageValue` you need to take a look at a [definition of this metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes): *"Percent of time over the past sample period (10s) during which the accelerator was actively processing. Values are integers between 0 and 100. Sampled every 60 seconds"*. Its hard to say what to set it to as it may depend on your specific workload so it may be good to just try several values and run some benchmarks.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Thank you so much.. @HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing our conversation in comments:

To make use of GCP metrics in kubernetes, [Custom Metrics Stackdriver Adapter](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling#step1) had to be deployed. This is why HPA was unable to read the metrics and therefore was throwing errors.